# How to setup IntelliJ IDEA for writing Java Kaa applications

Tags: intellij-idea, kaa

After following "Your first Kaa application" step-by-step guide at [this](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/#further-reading) link, I wished to develop a custom Java Kaa application using IntelliJ IDEA.
But, unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to setup my IDE in order to use its basic features (such as smart completion).

Can anyone suggest me a tutorial or a guide that could help me reaching my goal?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What did you do so far and on which step you have a problem? Share a project that you have now and specify what doesn't work in it.

Comment: Based on the answer that you have supplied, this question doesn't get close to describing the problem you were having, so I've voted to close it as unclear.

Comment: Hi @EngineerDollery, can you suggest me how to edit my answer in order to better describe the problems that I was having? Many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the end, that's what I suggest to do after some research and some trials:

1) Create a new empty Java Project in IntelliJ IDEA
2) Generate and download Kaa Java Endpoint SDK archive file (follow [Your first Kaa application](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/) guide for further informations)
3) Create a 'libs' folder in your Java project and move the .jar (something like *kaa-java-ep-sdk-***.jar*) in it
4) Create FirstKaaDemo.java file in 'src' folder and paste suggested Java application code in it.
5) Right-click on your project and Open Module Settings.
6) Add new JAR dependency and select your .jar file in 'libs' folder

This will solve every import error.
Hope this will help someone.

Comment: You're meant to be using maven for anything but the most trivial code.

Comment: Thanks @EngineerDollery for your help, I'm quite new to the programming world. I've ended up creating a new Gradle Project in IntelliJ IDEA and editing build.gradle file dependencies as follows:

dependencies {
   compile  files('./libs/kaa-java-ep-sdk-***.jar')
}

Is this the same as using Maven?

Comment: You should avoid gradle at all costs. It's rubbish (though quite popular with people who don't know better). Use maven.